# How to fix SQL group by and get expected result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got stuck while doing this query in PostgreSQL. i have done group by and it gave me proper result but i can not find my specific solution, what i actually want. Two column have been returned. But I want the sum of total_amount of this result and return just one column

```
SELECT pi.user_id, 
       Sum(total_amount) AS total_amount, 
       emp_id, 
       status, 
       max_pi_pending_amount, 
       first_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
       second_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
       emp_id, 
       Coalesce(pending_pi_amount, 0) AS pending_pi_amount 
FROM   proforma_invoice pi 
       JOIN users usr 
         ON pi.user_id = usr.user_id 
       JOIN employee emp 
         ON usr.employee_id = emp.emp_id 
       JOIN alarm_parameter ap 
         ON pi.user_id = ap.user_id 
WHERE  pi.user_id = 18 
       AND (status = 'Created' 
        OR status = 'Approved')
GROUP  BY pi.user_id, 
          status, 
          max_pi_pending_amount, 
          first_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
          second_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
          emp_id, 
          pending_pi_amount
```

[image: My query Result]

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: I have already added image.. bro..

Comment: One question: the Status column, can there be other statuses?

Comment: @MhDip - Is your image, the actual result you want ? or is it the result you are getting right now. Can you post both of them

Comment: Which contradicts what your text says: "Two column have been returned". There are much more than 2. You also said "I want the sum of total_amount", and you already have that. So your question is extremely unclear. If you want free help from us, clarify your question.

Comment: Yap there are other statuses but. i need a solution by using only these statuses :) :)

Comment: maybe the having clausel will help you?

Comment: According to the query the result is correct .. but i want the sum of total_amount on the basis of this result that means expected result should be (don't worry about the status just ignore the status)

user_id       total_amount 
18                 11024 (some of both total_amout) @SudiptaMondal

Comment: @JBNizet - I think, he meant rows and not columns ?

Comment: Then remove the status from the select clause and the group by clause.

Comment: @MhDip just remove `status` from the `group by` clause and from the `select` clause

Comment: or used having instead where

Comment: having and removing status from the group by clause didn't work for me.. :( :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to me you need subquery or cte

```
   with cte as
    (
    SELECT pi.user_id, 
           Sum(total_amount) AS total_amount, 
           emp_id, 
           status, 
           max_pi_pending_amount, 
           first_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
           second_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
           emp_id, 
           Coalesce(pending_pi_amount, 0) AS pending_pi_amount 
    FROM   proforma_invoice pi 
           JOIN users usr 
             ON pi.user_id = usr.user_id 
           JOIN employee emp 
             ON usr.employee_id = emp.emp_id 
           JOIN alarm_parameter ap 
             ON pi.user_id = ap.user_id 
    WHERE  pi.user_id = 18 
           AND (status = 'Created' 
            OR status = 'Approved')
    GROUP  BY pi.user_id, 
              status, 
              max_pi_pending_amount, 
              first_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
              second_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
              emp_id, 
              pending_pi_amount
    ) select user_id,sum(total_amount) from cte group by user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the status column from your query as it is invalid if it group together

```
SELECT pi.user_id, 
       Sum(total_amount) AS total_amount, 
       emp_id, 

       max_pi_pending_amount, 
       first_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
       second_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
       emp_id, 
       Coalesce(pending_pi_amount, 0) AS pending_pi_amount 
FROM   proforma_invoice pi 
       JOIN users usr 
         ON pi.user_id = usr.user_id 
       JOIN employee emp 
         ON usr.employee_id = emp.emp_id 
       JOIN alarm_parameter ap 
         ON pi.user_id = ap.user_id 
WHERE  pi.user_id = 18 
       AND (status = 'Created' 
        OR status = 'Approved')
GROUP  BY pi.user_id, 
          max_pi_pending_amount, 
          first_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
          second_pending_pi_warning_percentage, 
          emp_id, 
          pending_pi_amount
```